# How can i get the unique key violating column name at the time of execution in postgresql

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am inserting in multiple tables with foreach loop and I want unique-key column name due to which violating unique key constraints at the run time so i can modify the value and insert it.

```
foreach ($data as $table_name){

 $sql="INSERT INTO $table_name ($column_name) VALUES ($column_vlues)"

$result=query_params($db_conn,$sql,$params)
 if($result){
  //Do nothing. Its fine
}else{
 //If its voileting the unique key contraints then change the column value like new column value = $column_name_which_voileting.$value and then insert it.
 }
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: It gives you the name of the constraint, and you can deduce the column name(s) from that. What language and API are you using?

Comment: PHP, Postgresql @LaurenzAlbe

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pg_get_result_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error-field.php) to get the `PGSQL_DIAG_MESSAGE_PRIMARY`, which will contain the constraint name like this:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uni_id_key"
```

From that you can extract the name of the constraint. Then you can query `information_schema.constraint_column_usage` to find the columns associated with that constraint (if the constraint spans multiple columns, you might have to resort to `pg_catalog.pg_constraint` to find their relative position).

PostgreSQL actually sends the plain constraint name along with the error message, but PHP has no way to extract that error response field.